# how to fetch 100k data with in a second in spring boot in this query

Tags: ajax, spring-boot, java-8, hql

it takes too much time to fetch data.
after half an hour session out msg.
I want 100k data to fetch through ajax.

data increases day by day. after 1 year data across 400k then can not fetch data.

controller.java

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/showReportforDirectory", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody List<AlumniBeanForDirectory> showReport(HttpServletRequest request) {
        HttpSession session = null;
    
        List<AlumniBeanForDirectory> alumniRegDetailsList=null;
        if (request != null && request.getSession() != null) {
            session = request.getSession();
            if (session != null && session.getAttribute("isuseractive") != null
                    && !session.getAttribute("isuseractive").equals("")) {
                
            try {
                
                alumniRegDetailsList = alumniService.getAllAlumniRegDetails();
                
                }

            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        }
        return alumniRegDetailsList;
    }
```

service.java

```
@SneakyThrows
    @Override
    public List<AlumniBeanForDirectory> getAllAlumniRegDetails() {
        List<AlumniBeanForDirectory> alumniBeanList = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
        alumniBeanList = emptyIfNull(alumniDaoImpl.getAllAlumniRegistrationDetails()).stream().map(this::setAlumniDirectoryToBean)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return alumniBeanList;
    }
    
    private AlumniBeanForDirectory setAlumniDirectoryToBean(Object[] obj) {
        try {
        return AlumniBeanForDirectory.builder()
                .alumniPrimaryId((obj[0] !=null) ? ((BigInteger)obj[0]).longValue():0)
                .alumniName((obj[1] !=null) ? (obj[1]).toString():"NA")
                .alumniRegNo((obj[2] != null) ? (obj[2]).toString() : "NA")
                .passingYear((obj[3] != null) ? (obj[3]).toString() : "NA")
                .jnvNmae((obj[4] != null) ? ( globalFunction.getInstNameByInstId(Integer.parseInt((obj[4]).toString())) ): "NA")
                .fieldOfWork((obj[5] != null) ? (obj[5]).toString() : "NA")
                .countryName((obj[6] != null) ? (obj[6]).toString() : "NA")
                .email((obj[7] != null) ? (obj[7]).toString() : "NA")
                .contactNo((obj[8] != null) ? (obj[8]).toString() : "NA")
                .className((obj[9] != null) ? (obj[9]).toString() : "NA")
                .isNRI((obj[10] != null) ? ( (obj[10]).toString()=="0" ? "NO" :"YES") : "NA")
                .statusOfWorking((obj[11] != null) ? (obj[11]).toString() : "NA")
                .presentQualification((obj[12] != null) ? (obj[12]).toString() : "NA")
                .organization((obj[13] != null) ? (obj[13]).toString() : "NA")
                .designation((obj[14] != null) ? (obj[14]).toString() : "NA")
                .build();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Dao.java

```
    public List<Object[]> getAllAlumniRegistrationDetails() {
        List<Object[]> alumniRegistrationList = null;

        try {
            
            String query = "SELECT a.alumni_user_id, a.alumni_name, a.alumni_login_id, a.year_of_passing, "
                    + "a.jnv_name, a.fields_of_work_id, a.country_name, a.alumni_email, a.contact_no, a.class_passng_jnv, "
                    + "a.isnri, a.status_of_working, a.present_qualification, a.present_organisation, a.present_designation "
                    + "from sis.nvs_alumni_registration a where a.num_isvalid='1' ORDER BY a.alumni_user_id DESC ";
                    


            alumniRegistrationList=dataAccess.runNative(query.toString());
            
            
            
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return alumniRegistrationList;
    }
```

query to run more time i want to reduce the time. I have already add pagination through ajax. I want think create function for select query but problem is all rows did not fetch only one row fetch. how to resolve these problem

Comment: Please use universal measurements instead of local words like *lakh* that the rest of the world does not use or understand.

Comment: Any sample project can you share? Also can you use visual vm/jmh where is the bottleneck is? sometimes it might be the load all is the culprit